# Find correlation of random variables basing on joint density.

Tags: probability, covariance, correlation

Let $\xi$ and $\mu$ be independent random variables with the same Poisson distribution ($\lambda$ as the parameter). For any given natural $k\ge2$ consider random vector $(\gamma, \delta)$ with density given by $$P(\gamma = a, \delta = b) = P(\xi = a,\ \ \mu  = b \ \ |\  \xi + \mu =k)$$

Find the correlation of $\gamma$ and $ \delta$.

Attempt: using the definition of conditional probability one can obtain that given $k = a + b$ $$P(\gamma = a, \delta = b)= \frac{P(\xi = a,\ \ \mu  = k-b)}{P( \xi +\mu = k)}$$
Now from the fact that sum of Poission random variables is Poission random variable with the parameter equal of the sum of parameters of summed variables
$$P(\gamma = a, \delta = b)= \binom{a+b}{a} \frac{1}{2^{a+b}}$$

I approach the covariance with formula $cov(\gamma,\delta) = E(\gamma \delta)-E(\gamma)E(\delta)$. Trying to compute $E(\gamma \delta)$. If I am not wrong, it would be $\sum_{a\in\mathbb{N}} \sum_{b\in\mathbb{N}}ab\binom{a+b}{a} \frac{1}{2^{a+b}}$. But the series is divergent, therefore $E(\gamma \delta)$ is not a number.

Is it correct? I suspect that I misinterpret formula $E(f(n)) = \sum f(n)P(n)$ when trying to compute $E(\gamma \delta)$.

Comment: Since $\gamma + \delta=a+b=k$, which is given, the correlation seem likely to be $-1$

Comment: This was my guess since it is binominal distribution, therefore for each win more, the number of losses goes down, but I wanted to verify it and I hoped the additional effort would confirm it.

Comment: Your $\sum_{a\in\mathbb{N}} \sum_{b\in\mathbb{N}}ab\binom{a+b}{a} \frac{1}{2^{a+b}}$ looks unlikely since $a+b=k$.  How about $\sum_{a=0}^k a(k-a)\binom{k}{a} \frac{1}{2^{k}}$?